# Closure of Puppeteer Browser After Clicking Cookie Accept Button - Unexpected Behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a site to get live football (soccer) information, using node.js and puppeteer but my browser is closing immidiatly after the console.log("trying to select team element").

````
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function openPage() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {headless: true} );
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 926 });
  await page.goto("https://www.livescore.com/en/");

  // accepting cookies 
  const button = await page.waitForSelector('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler');
  if (button) {
    await button.click();
    console.log("clicked cookie button");
  };
  
  return page;
}

async function scrapeData(page) {
  let content = [];

  // Getting match elements
  let elements = await page.waitForSelector(".Ip")
  console.log("trying to select team element")


  for (let i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let homeTeamElement = await elements[i].$(".Ip")
    if (homeTeamElement) {
      const homeTeamText = await homeTeamElement.evaluate(node => node.textContent);
      content.push(homeTeamText);
    }
  };

  return content;
};

(async () => {
  const page = await openPage();
  const 
```
dataScraped = await scrapeData(page);
  console.log(dataScraped)

  await page.browser().close();
})();
````

Any idea why this may be and further critique on my code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Recommend adding more `console.logs` for debugging. E.g. Is `elements.length` > 0? What does your `console.log(dataScraped)` print, `[ ]`?

Comment: `await page.waitForSelector(".Ip")` only returns one element, not an array, so there's no way to loop over it. You should see an error message--what does Node print when your browser closes? I think you have an extra ``` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await page.waitForSelector(".Ip")` only returns one element, not an array, so there's no way to loop over it. There should be a clear error message to this effect. Instead, use `page.$$eval` (or the new [locators API](https://pptr.dev/guides/locators) if you're feeling cutting edge) to extract the data.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.0.2

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 926});
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

  // not really necessary
  const button = await page.waitForSelector("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler");
  await button.click();

  await page.waitForSelector(".Ip");
  const content = await page.$$eval(".Ip", els =>
    els.map(e => {
      const text = id =>
        e.querySelector(`[id*=${id}]`).textContent.trim();
      return {
        time: text("status-or-time"),
        home: text("home-team-name"),
        away: text("away-team-name"),
        homeTeamScore: +text("home-team-score"),
        awaitTeamScore: +text("away-team-score"),
      };
    })
  );
  console.log(content);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Notes:

- Closing the cookie banner isn't necessary for the scrape, but if you do use it, there's no point in checking the return value of `waitForSelector`. It's guaranteed to be the element, otherwise it'll throw if it can't find it in time.
- `await elements[i].$(".Ip")` isn't going to help you access anything, since there's no `.Ip` within the `.Ip` element you're already holding a handle to (as far as I can tell).
- Avoid ElementHandles--they're slow, unreliable and verbose.